# Не получаетсья изменить поле в БД который в миграции указан как default

Tags: laravel

Всем привет.

В миграции у меня есть поле которое по умолчанию стоит значение 0 мне надо его изменить на 1 все сделал вроде правильно но при запросе он выдает мне ошибку типо

**"Creating default object from empty value"**

Вот код миграции

```
public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('todos', function (Blueprint $table) {
            //тут создаем ячейки
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->string('todo');

            // NOTE : Put the default value of single quote and it will work
            $table->boolean('completed')->default(0); //строка из за которой выводятсья ошибка
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }
```

Маршрут

```
Route::get("/todo/completed/{id}",[
    "uses" => "TodosController@completed",
    "as" => "todo.completed"
]);
```

Функция внутри контроллера **TodosController**

```
public function completed($id){
        $idFromDb = Todo::find($id); //находим из БД ИД

        $idFromDb->completed = 1; //Меняем ИД ячейки completed которые взяли из БД с 0 на 1
        $idFromDb->save(); // сохраняем

        return redirect()->back();
    }
```

И view

```
@foreach($todos as $todo)
            <!-- 'id' параметры рута который присутсвуюет в контроллере и в БД -->
        {{$todo->todo}} <a href="{{ route('todo.delete', ['id' => $todo->id] ) }}" class="btn btn-danger">X</a>
                        <a href="{{ route('todo.update', ['id' => $todo->id] ) }}" class="btn btn-infor">Update</a>   
                        @if(!$todo->completed ) <!--в данном цикле у нас есть переменная $todo -->
                            <a href="{{ route('todo.completed', ['id' , $todo->id ]) }}" class="btn btn-xs btn-success">M. as Completed</a> 
                        @else 
                            <span class="txt-success">Completed!</span>

                        @endif      
        <hr>
    @endforeach
```

Помогите новичку в Laravel пожалуйста

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблема была тут

```
<a href="{{ route('todo.completed', ['id' , $todo->id ]) }}" class="btn btn-xs btn-success">M. as Completed</a>
```

Надо было не запятой поставить а больше и равно `=>` изменил  `['id' => $todo->id ]`